# A way to display currency?

Tags: python, localization

I have database values such as the following:

```
price      currency
10.99      USD
13.99      EUR
```

Is there a python library or something that I can use for help with displaying the currency properly on a storefront? For example, it should be:

```
10.99 USD ==> $10.99
13.99 EUR (france) ==> 13,99 €
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/docs/api/numbers/) like this:

```
import babel.numbers as numbers
print(numbers.format_currency(10.99, 'USD', locale='en_US'))
$10.99
print(numbers.format_currency(13.99, 'EUR', locale='fr_FR'))
13,99 €
```

PS. Under the hood, [money uses babel](https://github.com/carlospalol/money#installation) for locale-aware
formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the following python module accomplishes what you're looking to do:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/money